# Monotouch - WCF Binding Timeouts not being obeyed

Tags: xamarin.ios, wcf-binding

A service is created via the Silverlight service console program "slsvcutil"

We use this generated code and set timeouts, but the timeouts are not being obeyed. We have them set to 5 seconds, but the client doesn;t time out for over a minute (default)

```
svc = new MyServiceClient (........);
svc.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = Settings.TimeOutServiceOpen;
svc.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = Settings.TimeOutServiceClose;
svc.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = Settings.TimeOutServiceRecieve;
svc.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = Settings.TimeOutServiceSend;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a bug. Bug has been submitted to Monotouch team.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
svc.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = ....
```

This seems to work for me.